# Why is it to say 'paucis post diebus'?

Tags: preposition

In my Oxford Latin Course 2 chapter 21 there is a sentence 'paucis post diebus ubi Orbilius pueros dimisit'. Why is it not 'paucos post dies'? I remember that the preposition 'post' + accusative, doesnt it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this case, *post* is being used as an adverb, not a preposition; essentially, it's being treated as a comparative adverb*, and the ablative *paucis diebus* is expressing the 'degree of difference,' as it can do also with other comparative adverbs and adjectives**. So literally, the phrase means 'after by a few days.'

That said, *paucos post dies*, where *post* is a preposition patterning with an accusative, also works and has equivalent meaning.

* Just as the English word 'after' is, in origin, a comparative.

** For example, *multo felicior*, 'much happier' (literally, 'happier by much').

Answer (score 4):

Confusion between accusative/ ablative can occur with other expressions of time. The duration of a period of time, i.e. "how long" it lasted, requires the accusative. Occasionally the preposition, per, is used:

for two years = duos annos;

for many days = (per) multos dies.

But for "how long ago" something happened, you use the adverb, abhinc, normally with the accusative; but, it can also be used with the ablative, though this is less common:

two years ago = abhinc duos annos;

three days ago = tribus abhinc diebus.

Perhaps you are already aware that the adverb comes after at least one of the relevant words, in the ablative?

Comment: The information here is, in the main, correct; but this doesn't actually answer the question, does it? Unless you mean to suggest that paucis post diebus is an example of 'confusion between accusative/ ablative' and therefore somehow incorrect, which is simply not the case: paucis post diebus is a legitimate alternative construction to paucos post dies.

Comment: @cnread: it's an adjunct to the Q, hence "with other expressions of time". The OP seemed to be concerned about the circumstances dictating the use of the acc./ abl. cases.